# transaction fails due to out of gas in mainnet

Tags: go-ethereum, gas, etherscan, out-of-gas

Transaction fails due to out of gas though gas used by transaction is 22.32 % . What might be the reason ? I have give enough gas : 203000 wei.

Here is the [link](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2d948c0738eb05e1971edc558b2db2a004a9c5f3f34d0d2e51d59166389dec9b) of the transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transaction is failing with an Out of Gas error due to one of the calls within your contract not providing sufficient gas to complete its operation.

If you look at a [Parity trace](https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x2d948c0738eb05e1971edc558b2db2a004a9c5f3f34d0d2e51d59166389dec9b&type=parity) of your transaction, you can see that the call from `0x0adb0913c6a48078fdf16f77e9658b96fcc31633` to `0x8b094a45eab5131f8fdba6bfd169b33227969c63` failed. You will need to update your contract to increase the gas provided for that call.

In the [other](https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x19bf466e256d3e4311518f7eda3511073067d1dba1df6f01922c097d6edb923e&type=parity), successful, transaction that you provided, the address receiving the ether on the failed call is not a contract. In all probability, the contract you are sending ether to in the failed tx performs some operation in its fallback function that exceeds 2300 gas.

Comment: Wow great ! I got it. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why transaction fails is not enough gas.

Though the transaction fails, transaction signer must pay a portion of gas.

[normal transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x50d8f294c23fab0a5faad167c641baaf72a37adf66223a035086485e103a25e7)( only sending ETH)  pay 52831 gas, more expensive than your transaction.

Comment: Yes I get it . In this transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2d948c0738eb05e1971edc558b2db2a004a9c5f3f34d0d2e51d59166389dec9b I have given enough gas 203000. If it is out of gas it should use up all the gas and fail out of gas. But in my case it has just used 45318.

Comment: Here it is a successful normal transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0x19bf466e256d3e4311518f7eda3511073067d1dba1df6f01922c097d6edb923e for the same operation and same gasLimit 203000. This was success.

Comment: Can you show solidity code?