# Why 'Out of gas' error when there is still a lot of gas?

Tags: contract-development, vyper

- Gas limit was set to 6,000,000
- Tx consumed just 1,943,125

Yet is still failed with `Out of gas` error.

If it makes any difference, this is my contract which calls other contracts with `raw_call` (in Vyper) and passes the full remaining gas to those calls.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6c7de51a6232521a607a9cfc3ca785c002bf25e51cdd4faa0335f9693b2f07f5

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62889/transaction-fails-due-to-out-of-gas-in-mainnet

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty hard to tell from just the raw transaction, but if you look here: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6c7de51a6232521a607a9cfc3ca785c002bf25e51cdd4faa0335f9693b2f07f5/advanced#internal you can see that the transaction makes a couple of calls where it's only passing in 5,000 gas to another contract.  I'd check if you really are passing in the full gas all the time, as not passing in enough gas would definitely cause this...